# Save '\' to char variable

Tags: c#, char

`\` is reserved character, so its somewhat problematic.

I'm trying to do this:

```cs
fileName.Substring(fileName.LastIndexOf('\') + 1);
```

But it returns plenty of errors, because it recognizes everything after `\` as string, even though its one character.

I'm 100% sure there is a solution for that and it has been asked dozens of times, but I swear I cannot find anything here or on google.

Comment: Even stackoverflow indicates the error --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/akK0A.png

Comment: Don't do *string manipulations* with *files*: if you want to extract file name, just do it: `Path.GetFileName(fileName);`

Comment: Agree with Dmitry's comment - do not do what you're doing. Use methods like `Path.GetFileName`, `Path.GetDirectoryName`, `Path.GetExtension` etc. Paths on Windows are permitted to be like `c:/windows/system32` and on unix are always using `'/'`, so your code is inherently fragile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape it with another `\`:

`fileName.Substring(fileName.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);`

Read more in doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/escape-sequences?view=msvc-160

Comment: Marking as solution once stack will allow me (need to wait 15 minutes).